Array of types that take a generic argument?
I have this item interface:
interface Item<Href extends string> {
  href: Route<Href>
}

I want to have a component that takes a list of these Item in a single property:
interface Props {
  items: Item[]
}

const Component = (props: Props): ReactNode => { ... };

<Component items={[
  { href: '/' },
  { href: '/auth' },
]} />

How can I make this work? Currently it complains because I'm not passing the generic to the Item interface when I define Props.

const Component = <T,>(props: Props<T>): ReactNode => { ... };?

@Konrad is the generic going to assume the value of each Item? I mean, it's a single variable, but it's going to pass the correct value to each Item<T> initialization?

Thanks to @Konrad's comment, the solution was simpler than I expected.
It was enough to add a generic to the component type
Here's a full example:
import * as React from 'react';
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';

type StaticRoutes = '/' | '/auth'
type Route<T extends string> = T extends StaticRoutes ? T : never;

interface Item<Href extends string> {
  href: Route<Href>
}

interface Props<T extends string> {
  items: Item<T>[]
}

const Component = <T extends string,>(props: Props<T>): ReactNode => { 
  return null;
 };

const App = () => <Component items={[
  { href: '/' },
  { href: '/auth' },
]} />

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQokscMAnmFnAN6ZUwByEACacAvnCIlylPDFp06bDnADKMZDGC4MEAK4ws6ALzkA9GTgAfM8n0ALMovacd+rAB4AKnCwAPAwB2QuioMFDAAQDmAHxwJt5+gcGq6praegboAPxw3gBccAFYAG5YUPQMAQZQBHicAJIGIO4AEpQEPv5YQSFhETHcdHBwdu0Frgat7dF0ogoR1bW4nAAKxGCoXp1JveFRsVxDcMBNqAWNWM2e0QDaALqzCrgQAaFwAMIkkEVVcXBbiW6yVCe0iABpogAKMDrM5wNYQDZeaIASnGfEEIjiBzgR0oMF0UAChV0ABtSfQ4KIKs9XvAAIJgMB-SEo7H-T7gF7deAnS6oIxcG5HHijLAEApkcxUsEikZjGz2CyiWV3cSmaJAA

I believe that you should specify the type as well, you are defining in your item to get a Href that extends from string, so you can do the same in the Props interface or set string directly.
I made this quick example:
import './App.css'

import { ReactNode } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'


interface Item<Href extends string> {
  href: Href,
  component?: ReactNode
}

interface Props {
  items: Array<Item<string>>
}

const Component = ({ items }: Props): ReactNode => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <Routes>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <Route key={index} path={item.href} element={item.component} />
          ))}
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

const ITEMS: Array<Item<string>> = [
  { href: '/', component: <h1>Dashboard</h1> },
  { href: '/auth', component: <h1>Auth</h1> },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Component items={ITEMS} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

It is a good practice to use Array instead of Type[] or [Type], it is easier to read.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
